# Is My PDO Prepared Statement Secure If I Bind The Parameters In The Execute Function?

Tags: php, security, pdo, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I have some form data that I'm writing to a database with PDO prepared statements.

This form data is santized and validated on the on the way in to the database with `filter_var()` functions and regular expressions and when any of this data is outputted to the site it escaped with `htmlspecialchars()`.

To prevent SQL injections I'm using I'm using the code below. When I first learnt PDO this was what I saw in the tutorial and I personally find it very easy to read/understand.

I've noticed on the php.net site and in some other code I've saw recently they used bindparams(), whereas in the code below I've always done this inside an array in the `execute()` method.

Is my code below secure? Or must I use bindparams in the way that is shown in the second code example?

Here is some sample code using a firstname input from a webform

```
<?php

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];

$firstname = filter_var($fname, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if(empty(trim($fname))){
    $error[] = "First Name cannot be blank";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (firstname) VALUES (:firstname)";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([
    ':firstname' => $firstname,
]);
```

In the php.net docs it does the above prepared statement using `bindParam()`, which seems a little verbose if you are updating a number of fields?

```
<?php
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (firstname) VALUES (:firstname)";

$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
$stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);

$stmt->execute();
```

If it is more secure then I'll obviously have to do it the second way, but wanted to check if my prepared statements given in the first code block are secure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine either way. The security benefit is from using placeholders at all. There are some cases (dynamically constructed queries) where it's beneficial to use `bindParam` separately from the `execute` call, and there are others where you would prefer to avoid the verbosity. Use what suits you.